# Multiple network type on openstack

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-neutron

This is very strange question, I am planning to build Openstack with latest code, but related network implementation i want to do multiple type like `VLAN` and `tenant` type of network, let me explain.

- Type 1 - I want i can select what kind of networking my instance going to use, like i can set VLAN type so my instance directly get IP of my existing provider LAN ( no NAT etc, direct IP on instance)
- Type 2 - Where i create instance with tenant style where instance will have private IP from (VPC) and it will NAT'ed with floating IP for outside access.

Doing hybrid network is possible in openstack or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible to have support of two types of networking which is mentioned in the question.

Here is link for ubuntu openstack installation **https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/install/controller-install-option2-ubuntu.html#configure-the-modular-layer-2-ml2-plug-in

After successful installation of openstack:

1. Create a VLAN network which is provider network/external network (provider network + internet access) which doesn't require the NAT'ing.
2. Create a local/internal network which is accessible with-in the tenant/project. As the network is local the VM which uses this can only be accessible in the tenant.

**Option-1**: **Using provider/external network:**

Use this network for launching the VM and the VM is accessible outside the tenant/project.

**Option-2**: **Using the internal/NAT/Floating**:

Use this network to launch the VM and allocate floating IP from floating IP pool so that can be accessed from outside tenant.